# Store float value as separated by comma instead of dot in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to display float value as separated by comma instead of dot.

For example

Need to show `123,50` instead of `123.50`

I used `number_format('123.50','2',',','')` for this.

But this is pain to me because i need to show this in many places.

Is possible to store these float value as separated by comma in database...? Because these values are coming from database where it has the type as `float(10,2)`.

Comment: Is a pretty bad ideas switch your database to "," separated floats, the best solution is use number_format in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible, the values in the database are floating point numbers as understand by the computer. You should format them on the PHP side after you retrieve those values.

```
number_format($row['field'], 2, ',');
```

If you change the type of the column to a `VARCHAR` or some other text-based then you would be able to store numeric values as text with comma as decimal point. **But please don't!** The numeric types are made for numeric content. There are many advantages of using numeric columns over strings.

The general idea is to retrieve the data once, format it once, and **only then** use it in all pages. If your design does not allow to change the format **in one place**, then it suggests it may be flawed. Read about [MVC](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) for a good design practices.